# Find strings in PostgreSQL and order by distance to beginning of string

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to write a query that looks up a partial string, but order by proximity to the front of the string. It's for a typeahead application.

Here's my query currently:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT ON (full_name) full_name
FROM users
WHERE (lower(full_name) LIKE 'q%' OR lower(full_name) LIKE '%q%')
LIMIT 10
```

But it does not seem to order in the way I would expect.

So if I search for 'pet' I would like to return `peter smith` and `petra glif` before `abigail peters`.

Is it possible to write that where clause in this way? We don't currently have any fuzzy text search modules installed in the database so I would like to avoid doing that if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use boolean expression `full_name ILIKE 'q%'` as a sort order.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT full_name
    FROM users
    WHERE full_name ILIKE '%q%'
    ) alias
ORDER BY full_name ILIKE 'q%' DESC, full_name
LIMIT 10
```

Note that there is `ILIKE` operator for case-insensitive `LIKE`.

You may be also interested in [Full Text Search](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/textsearch-intro.html).

Answer (score 5):

You can use position(substring in string) function for this:

```
order by position(lower('pet') in lower(full_name))
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html

Comment: I like the look of this answer but I get the following `ERROR:  SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions` which a couple google searches tell me I will not be able to resolve. I edited the query above.

Comment: Get my query and replace `order by` with David's proposal.

Comment: If you like this idea (I do!) then the answer deserves upvoting.